# Send HTML email in Appengine [PYTHON] using HTML file

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I want to send a HTML email to the users after they signup to the website. Earlier I wrote this script to send

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
                            subject="Your account has been approved")

message.to = "Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>"

message.body = """
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
"""

message.html = """
<html><head></head><body>
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
</body></html>
"""
message.send()
```

But instead of placing the HTML directly in the main code, I want to have a separate HTML file which would be used as a body. 
I tried to do it as follows:

```
message.html = 'emailHTML.html'
```

but in vain. How can I use a HTML file in the place of HTML code?

Comment: Have you tried using the `open()` and `.readlines() or .read()` commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this would be to [use a templating engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) to load and generate the HTML as a string from the HTML file. For example, if you use the [webapp2 jinja2 extras](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html) package, you could do something along the lines of:

```
from webapp2_extras import jinja2 as webapp_extras_jinja2
# ...

def get_message_html():
  jinja2 = webapp_extras_jinja2.get_jinja2()
  return jinja2.render_template('relative/path/to/template.html')

# ...
def send_email():
   # ...
   message.html = get_message_html()
   # ...
```

Note that to get this working, you need to add jinja2 to the libraries section of app.yaml as in:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: 2.5.2
- name: jinja2
  version: 2.6
```

... and you also need to include an appropriate 'webapp2_extras.jinja2' to the app config. Ex:

```
config = {
   'webapp2_extras.jinja2': {
     'template_path': 'path/containing/my/templates',
     'environment_args': {
       # Keep generated HTML short
       'trim_blocks': True,
       'extensions': [
         # Support auto-escaping for security
         'jinja2.ext.autoescape',
         # Handy but might not be needed for you
         'jinja2.ext.with_'
         # ... other extensions? ...
       ],
       # Auto-escape by default for security
       'autoescape': True
     },
     # .. other configuration options for jinja2 ...
   },
   # ... other configuration for the app ...
},
# ...
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes, is_debug_enabled, config)
```

While you can just as easily open the HTML file yourself, the benefit of using a templating engine such as jinja2 is that it will encourage you to compose and reuse the HTML in a more sane way (whereas simply loading the HTML file might result in you eventually applying substitutions by hand). Also, just a quick security reminder: if any of the data you include in the email comes from untrusted sources (like the user or another user), make sure to properly validate and sanity-check the content (and also enable auto-escaping in the templating engine).

You can obviously choose a templating other than jinja2, but I specifically chose that one for my answer since it is well supported and well documented for App Engine.

Answer (score 4):

You can set

```
message.html = open('emailHTML.html').read()
```

to get exactly the same effect as what you're doing now; or, you could have the HTML as an **attachment** (so the email's body is just the plain text one, but the recipient can download the HTML as an attachment) with:

```
message.attachments = [('emailHTML.html', open('emailHTML.html').read())]
```

I'm not quite sure what you'd hope to accomplish in either case, but these are pretty much the only two possibilities I can think of.  If neither is satisfactory, please edit your Q to explain exactly what you want this email to look like to the user (is the body supposed to be plain or html, is there supposed to be an attachment...?).

Comment: @WasimThabraze, if you haven't first written the file `'emailHTML.html'`, of course the file in question won't exist, and trying to open and read it will cause errors.  Before you read the file it must exist -- that's a given!-)  How you choose to create it is a completely different issue (in app engine you cant write files, so it needs to be a read-only data file uploaded as part of your app).

Comment: @WasimThabraze, you need to ensure that the file is included in those the sources that are pushed to the server and also that you are using a correct relative path. The "app.yaml" file configures which files are or are not included in the list of files that get uploaded (some files are skipped by default).